# Thunar warning content type loading failed

Tags: bash, thunar, glib

I'm running a bash script that collates and organises files before turning it into a zip. When I run the script, multiple Thunar 'warnings' and 'critials' pop that I have a hard time figuring out what they are about (see image). This occurs while the script is copying over files.

It mentions a Content type loading error for a strangely named file that I can't place. What generates these warnings?

```
thunar-WARNING **: 16:45:16.720: Content type loading failed for sedVOTg4r: Error when getting information for file /path/to/file/sedVOTg4r : No such file or directory

GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 16:45:16.722: g_file_info_get_attribute_uint32: assertion 'G_IS_FILE_INFO (info)' failed
```

[image: error message]

The script looks as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash


subj=$1
outBase=$2
echo $subj
echo $outBase
subj_site_list=path/to/scripts/subj_site_list.txt

#########   make/check dir structure exists     ########

outStudy=${outBase}/Leapeuaims_2
if [[ ! -d "${outStudy}" ]] ; then
    mkdir ${outStudy}
fi

## Set matching site collection for the particular subject
site=$(awk -v search="$subj" '{gsub(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/, "");} $1 == search {print $2}' "$subj_site_list" | tr -d '\r')

echo "${subj} is a ${site} participant"
echo

if [ "$site" = "University1" ]; then 
    outCentre=${outStudy}/University1
elif [ "$site" = "University2" ]; then 
    outCentre=${outStudy}/University2
elif [ "$site" = "999" ]; then
    echo ">> site code 999, skipping subject $subj"
    sed --in-place "/$subj/d" ./logfile.txt
    echo ">> site code 999, skipping subject $subj" >> logfile.txt
    echo
    exit
else
    echo ">> subject $subj not listed; check for withdrawn consent"
    echo
fi

echo "site parameter set to $outCentre"
echo
    
if [[ ! -d "${outCentre}" ]] ; then
    mkdir ${outCentre}
fi

## Make BOLD folder for preprocessed data
BOLD=${outCentre}/BOLD
if [[ ! -d "${BOLD}" ]] ; then
    mkdir ${BOLD}
    mkdir ${BOLD}/Preprocessed
fi


#######  Check what subj data exists/mk dirs and copy over/rename as needed per modality #########


indir=/path/to/subject_data/$subj/

echo "Wrapping contents ${indir}"
echo


#BOLD
if ls $indir/BOLD_data/preprocessing/* 1> /dev/null 2>&1; then
    subjbold=${BOLD}/Preprocessed/${subj}
    mkdir $subjbold
    rsdir=${subjbold}/Resting_state
    mkdir $rsdir
    echo "adding preprocessed resting state data"
    cp -r $indir/BOLD_data/preprocessing/* $rsdir/
    echo "done"
    echo
else
    echo ">> no preprocessed data found for $subj"
    echo
    sed --in-place "/$subj/d" ./logfile.txt
    echo "${subj}: no fMRI data found" >> logfile.txt
fi
```

Comment: It looks as if your script is attempting to copy temporary or non-existent files, as evidenced by: `No such file or directory`  The Object assertions are normal when trying to use an application written for a Desktop Environment in a Terminal

Comment: Interesting. Nowhere in my script I explicitly copy anything from that directory at all, so where could this behavior come from?

Comment: Whatever the path id that you blotted out for anonymity + the file `sedVOTg4r` don't exist at runtime, therefore Thunar cannot find the icon for that file because the file doesn't exist.

Comment: Can you add the script? Without seeing the script, we can only guess

Comment: No problem @Vilinkameni, I have added the script, I hope it is readable enough, if not please let know. I guess somewhere along these (temporary?) files like sedVOTg4r are made. I guess, now I see this filename this would be related somehow to the sed --inplace lines?

Comment: As @eyoung100 stated, it is normal that GUI applications run from terminal print a bunch of warnings. As for the question itself, again as stated: the warnings are generated by Thunar when it notices the file (its name looks like a temporary file name btw), tries to access it to obtain content type information about it for whatever reason, and at that moment the file is gone. If you suspect the file is generated by your script, you can use the `-v` flag of **cp** or something like `watch ls whatever_dir`. Off topic: run the script through https://shellcheck.net for some general suggestions.

Comment: Thanks, that's a very helpful website! The thing is though, this script is not part of a GUI application at all. But of I understand correctly I shouldn't read to much into these errors, correct?

Comment: I just realized don't should be doesn't in the previous comment I made.  Aside from that, run the script from a true terminal.  I believe what you're doing is watching for file creation/logging by running the script by double clicking it from inside Thunar.  Don't do that.  Close Thunar but keep the terminal app open or use a terminal outside of X (Ctrl + Alt + Function Key[Start at F2]) and the handy `./` shortcut as in `./scriptname`

Comment: Hi @eyoung100. I run the script from terminal using either './scriptname' or 'bash scriptname' as commands. The warnings pop up as soon as the sed --in-place commands in the script is triggered so it seems to be related to the temporary copy of logfile.txt that the sed command generates. The output of the sed command seems normal though.

Comment: Where are you creating logfile.txt?  Read @Vilinkameni's comment again.  That is what's happening.  You might want to try from a plain terminal as I suggested earlier.  You can also `touch logfile.txt` to create a blank copy then read in all the elements in your nested if  and perform the `sed` last, ie read in all the elements even 999 and then remove them all AFTER processing, NOT DURING.  The only reason the error is being generated is because of the File Manager seeing and trying to index the file and icon for faster loading.

Comment: I also just reread my first comment RE: Desktop Environments.  The converse is also true.  The warning will be thrown when trying to use a "Terminal-only" app inside a desktop which is what you're doing. See [the Console Switching HOWTO](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Keyboard-and-Console-HOWTO-7.html), and this [Tech Tip on Switching Consoles](https://ostechnix.com/how-to-switch-between-ttys-without-using-function-keys-in-linux/)